# Why won't Rails work in a second Terminal window?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

I want to run `rails server` in one Terminal window and work in another Terminal window, but the second window doesn't work, even though I would expect the two windows to function identically.

When I type `rails` (much less `rails s`, etc.) in that second window, I get this error:

```
Could not find jquery-rails-2.0.2 in any of the sources
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.
```

My understanding is that `bundle install` shouldn't be necessary (as it had already been taken care of in the first window and everything is functioning properly), and I've made sure everything is as it should be with `which ruby` and `rvm use <my gemset>`, etc. The second Terminal window assures me that I am using the appropriate Ruby version and gemset, yet does not work.

Meanwhile, the original Terminal window continues to work exactly as it should -- I just keep having to exit out of Rails server in order to keep working, which is annoying.

Is there something painfully obvious here that I don't understand about working in a second Terminal window? I wouldn't have expected much setup to be required.

Comment: It should work - if as you've said RVM has been set to use the right ruby etc.  Really stupid suggestion - are you sure you're in the directory of your rails application in the second window?

Comment: What happens if you type `bundle exec rails s` in your second window?

Comment: As Michael said, everything you mentioned (assuming you really did check to ensure you had correct ruby and gemset in the 2nd windows that's identical to your first window) should be working. Are you sure you're in the same project folder as the first window?

Comment: For whatever reason, I suspect you're not using the ruby and/or gemset you believe you are. Consider using a `.rvmrc` file containing `rvm use ruby-x.x.x@gemset-name --create` so when you enter the directory the busywork is handled for you.

Comment: Michael, Terminal is in the correct directory. And trust me, at this stage of my learning, nothing is a stupid suggestion!

Comment: Dave, I've previously set both RVM and my gemset as the default, so that shouldn't be an issue as far as I know, but I'll double check.

Comment: Gareth, I get the same error when I type bundle exec rails s.

Comment: Does "gem list" give identical results in both windows? Something tells me it won't be identical - something is missing.

Comment: Craig, you're right -- the lists don't match. Somewhere along the line I must have created an unintentional discrepancy between my project and my Terminal defaults, which is surely causing the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Update, for anyone else who runs into this problem: Just plain old "rvm use" fixed it in the new window, and now any other new window I open works. Might be something to try if you're experiencing the same issue, Future Googler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite my efforts to make sure they did, the gemsets between the two Terminal windows did not match. This was discovered using `gem list` and comparing the two outputs.

Comment: I am having this problem too. I am in the correct directory. But the second terminal window does not work as the `gem list` listed different outputs. I am following the `http://ruby.railstutorial.org` tutorial.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is still struggling use:

```
rvm use 2.1.0
```

2.1.0 is your ruby version.